# Integration over a formula including arcsin

Tags: calculus, integration

When i calulate a probability formula, i met a double integration as follows:
$$\int^{\rho}_{0}\int^{\rho}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} dr_{1}dr_{2}$$
where,
$$t=(1-r_{1}^2)(1-r_{2}^2)+(1-r_{1}^2)(1-\rho^2)+(1-r_{2}^2)(1-\rho^2)+2(1-r_{1}r_{2})(1-\rho^2)+2(1-r_{1}\rho)(1-r_{2}^2)+2(1-r_{2}\rho)(1-r_{1}^2)$$

To calculate such an integration, i first integrate over $dr_{2}$ and get:
$$\int^{\rho}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-r_{1}^2-2\rho r_{1}-\rho^2+4}}{(s-t)dr_{1}}$$
where,
$$s = arcsin\frac{-2\rho_{1}r_{1}^2+(1-3\rho^{2})r_{1}+\rho(3-\rho^{2})}{2(-r_{1}^2-\rho r_{1}+3-\rho^{2})}$$
$$t = arcsin\frac{(1-\rho^{2})r_{1}+(1-r_{1}^2)\rho}{2(-r_{1}^2-\rho r_{1}+3-\rho^{2})}$$

And i don`t know what to do next to solve such a long integration. So, i just wonder can this double integration finally be solved, even with a long answer. And i really need help for the direction to solve(detail can be ignored). I should integrate over $dr_{1}$ next or just start from double integartion and change of variables.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: May we assume that $0<\rho\le1$ so as to guarantee $t\ge0$?

Comment: yeah,$\rho$is correlation

Comment: I'm mostly sure the value of the integral in the $\rho=1$ case is $I=\frac{2\pi^{2}}{15}$. If you're lucky, perhaps the general case can be reduced to dilogarithms.

Comment: Thanks so much. Dilogarithms is quite a possible result. Hope i am lucky enough.